# how to tell firefox to shutdown cleanly from tty1?

Tags: debian, command-line, firefox

Lately I run Firefox almost exclusively from on one of my Debian laptops (which run testing). Occasionally (~monthly) my desktop/tty7 hangs, in which case I usually can goto tty1 and `sudo shutdown -[whatever] now` . Unfortunately this does not cause Firefox to shut down as cleanly as I'd like: notably, when I bring it back up after OS restart, I must restore a crashed session. Which usually is not a problem, but sometimes is.

ISTM, for this usecase, I should be able to utter something (before shutdown) from tty1 to tell Firefox to shutdown cleanly. I know [what to tell Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18171/how-to-tell-graphical-emacs-to-shutdown-cleanly-from-tty1), but not what to tell Firefox. How to do this? FWIW, the following do not work:

1. `killall -HUP firefox1`

When I do that in (the bash terminal @) tty1, and goto tty7, Firefox is indeed gone. But when I restart Firefox (in tty7), Firefox comes up with dialog title=`Session Manager - Restore after Crash` and offers a crashed session.

2. `killall -SIGHUP $(pidof firefox)`

(Note: I substituted `$()` for the backticks used in the [candidate answer below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244870/38638) to make Markdown happy, but when I ran from tty1, I used the backticks, though I'm quite sure `bash` does not care.) This does not work at all for me, but I'm not sure why: when I do the following in tty1,

```
$ killall -SIGHUP `pidof firefox`
24586: no process found
$ pidof firefox
24586
$ pgrep -l firefox
24586 firefox
```

... and then goto tty7, Firefox is still there.

3. `pkill -HUP firefox`

Results identical to item#=1 above.

Comment: `killall` expects a name or pattern, NOT a pid. `kill -HUP $(pidof xyz)` does the same as `killall -HUP xyz` (and vice versa!)

Answer (score 0):

killall -HUP firefox should do it gracefully.

Comment: alas, no: when I (1) `killall -HUP firefox` in tty1 (2) restart Firefox in tty7, I get 'Your last session Crashed!'

Answer (score 0):

The following command will solve your issue:

```
killall -SIGHUP `pidof firefox`
```

But how to handle the problem that your tty7 hangs after one month of use? Rather than reboot or shutdown, I would suggest

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
```

This will drop OS caches, thus releasing more memory for applications.

Comment: Alas, no, the `killall` commandline fails as noted in my updated question. But thanks for the `drop_caches`: I'm not sure that it will fix the tty7 problem (I'll try that next time), but in my current LMDE/Cinnamon session, it did increase free memory by 30%! I suspect this is because Cinnamon caches fairly aggressively, but ICBW.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
wmctrl -c "Mozilla Firefox"
```

or

```
wmctrl -c "Firefox"
```

Reference: https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl